# Support Vector Machine Visualization in R

Tags: r, visualization, svm

I am having trouble graphing my SVM model in R. The formula is:

```
svm_linear <- svm(open ~ review_count + recession + duration + count + stars + Freq + avgRev + avgStar, data=yelp_train, cost=100, gamma=1)
plot(svm_linear, data=yelp_train)
```

I can't figure out why nothing appears after running the plot function. Please help. 
I added the dput out.

I cut out some of the extra columns to avoid waste.

```
newdata <- cleanDataFrame[2:10]
set.seed(10)
(newdata[sample(1:nrow(newdata), 30),])

structure(list(open = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), review_count = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 38L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
 23L, 19L, 3L, 22L, 74L, 15L, 38L, 88L, 26L, 9L, 3L, 58L, 4L, 
13L, 117L, 38L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 102L, 108L, 264L, 103L), stars = c(3, 
4, 4.5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 2.5, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.5, 4, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 4, 3, 3.5, 4), Freq = c(166L, 
12L, 166L, 15L, 45L, 166L, 66L, 79L, 33L, 58L, 150L, 389L, 150L, 
1L, 389L, 20L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 166L, 74L, 0L, 389L, 32L, 389L, 
161L, 126L, 389L, 98L, 3L), avgRev = c(23.7904191616766, 18.7692307692308, 
23.7904191616766, 98, 78.804347826087, 23.7904191616766, 31.3283582089552, 
64.3375, 23.1764705882353, 23.6949152542373, 60.6490066225166, 
34.1923076923077, 60.6490066225166, 22, 34.1923076923077, 33.1904761904762, 
34.1923076923077, 34.1923076923077, 34.1923076923077, 30.8443113772455, 
27.6533333333333, 117, 34.1923076923077, 30.4545454545455, 34.1923076923077, 
37.2716049382716, 47.3149606299213, 34.1923076923077, 64.3838383838384, 
73.75), avgStar = c(3.53592814371257, 3.92307692307692, 3.53592814371257, 
3.96875, 3.6195652173913, 3.53592814371257, 3.69402985074627, 
3.58125, 3.5, 3.67796610169492, 3.63245033112583, 3.5551282051282, 
3.63245033112583, 4, 3.5551282051282, 3.78571428571429, 3.5551282051282, 
3.5551282051282, 3.5551282051282, 3.48203592814371, 3.72666666666667, 
4.5, 3.5551282051282, 3.65151515151515, 3.5551282051282, 3.43827160493827, 
3.63385826771654, 3.5551282051282, 3.60606060606061, 4.25), count = c(4L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 15L, 4L, 3L, 15L, 14L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 1L, 27L, 4L, 51L, 36L, 14L), 
recession = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), duration = c(332L, 427L, 614L, 117L, 1894L, 
1346L, 140L, 1909L, 1100L, 1030L, 1666L, 2096L, 1054L, 352L, 
2145L, 1018L, 1763L, 391L, 2116L, 1567L, 693L, 674L, 1626L, 
301L, 295L, 378L, 649L, 376L, 1028L, 2390L)), .Names = c("open", 
"review_count", "stars", "Freq", "avgRev", "avgStar", "count", 
"recession", "duration"), row.names = c(1439L, 870L, 1210L, 1962L, 
242L, 639L, 777L, 771L, 1741L, 1214L, 1840L, 1603L, 322L, 1681L, 
1010L, 1209L, 148L, 745L, 1124L, 2354L, 2433L, 1731L, 2180L, 
1000L, 1141L, 1985L, 2814L, 674L, 2163L, 999L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the package `svm` comes from, but my first 2 (perhaps obvious questions) would be: 1) does svm have a default plotting function that gets called when you call `plot`? 2) is your graphics device correctly specified?

Comment: If this is `svm` from the package `e1071`, then it does have a `plot.svm` method.

Comment: Expanding on @JPC's comment, you could try running `dev.off()` and re-running your plot command. If you had a plot `device` open without realizing it, `dev.off()` will clear it and reset you to the default device (which is wherever your plots usually show up if you don't explicitly specify another output device). For example, if you're using RStudio, the default device is the RStudio plot window.

Comment: The `plot.svm` method requires that you select two dimensions at a time for visualization. Try something like this and see if you get a plot: `plot(svm_linear, formula = Freq ~ avgRev, data=yelp_train)`.

Comment: This is from the e1071 package. I was using the native Rstudio graphics, and also tried win.graph()
The plot.svm isn't available for the newest version of R. :( 

I also wasn't sure if the problem is with my data.

Comment: Use `plot` not `plot.svm`. `plot.svm` is a hidden function that is called by `plot` when you try to plot an `svm` object. Try running this code and see what happens: `plot(svm_linear, formula = Freq ~ avgRev, data=yelp_train)`.

Comment: If you post some data it would be easier to help you further. Use the `dput` function, like so: `dput(yelp_train[sample(1:nrow(yelp_train), 30),])`. (This will give 30 randomly selected rows. Run e.g. `set.seed(10)` first to make it exactly reproducible.) Paste the output into your question.

Comment: Please try it again, but post exactly what is printed to your console when you run `dput`. For example, if you run `dput(cars[1:5,])` with the built-in `cars` data set, you get the following: `structure(list(speed = c(4, 4, 7, 7, 8), dist = c(2, 10, 4, 22, 16)), .Names = c("speed", "dist"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")`. You should get similar output that starts with the word "structure".

Comment: Fixed it for you. Check OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do classification, but your outcome variable is integer mode. To see this, do `str(yelp_train)`. Turn the outcome into a factor and then try your plot again. For example:

```
yelp_train$openF = factor(yelp_train$open)

svm_linear <- svm(openF ~ review_count + recession + duration + count + stars + Freq + avgRev +
                         avgStar, data=yelp_train, cost=100, gamma=1)

plot(svm_linear, formula = review_count ~ Freq, data=yelp_train)
```

One other thing. In the portion of the data you provided, `recession` is always zero. If this is the case with all of the data, then remove `recession` from your call to `svm`. I had to do this to avoid an error. Once I removed `recession`, I was able to run the model and plot several combinations of variables successfully.

**Question in Comments: Why isn't `Open` the dependent variable in the formula in the plot function?** You're plotting where the decision boundary lies in relation to the values of two of the independent variables (or "features" in machine learning lingo). The predicted value of the dependent variable, `Open`, is given by the fill colors: In this case, one color for `Open=1` and another for `Open=0`. The boundary between the two colors is the decision boundary that the svm model came up with. The plot also includes points representing the pairs of values of the two features used for the plot. The two different plot markers represent the two different values of `Open` and you can see how many points were properly classified and how many were misclassified by your model.

The full decision boundary is a hyperplane in a multi-dimensional space. For example, if you had 3 features in the model, the features would lie in a 3-dimensional space (imagine a 3D scatterplot) and the decision boundary would be a 2-dimensional hyperplane through that 3D space (which we of course refer to as a "plane" in this case; and in general, the decision boundary has dimension one less than the dimension of the feature space).

When you plot two features, you're looking at a two-dimensional slice through that multi-dimensional space. The plot function is setting the values of the other features to some specific values--maybe the mean for numeric variables and the base factor level for factor variables--check the documentation to be sure. The plot function for svm models allows you to set the specific values of the other features (besides the two you're plotting) using the `slice` argument. That allows you to see how the decision boundary for two particular features varies based on changes in the values of other features.

You might find the svm chapter of [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/index.html) useful for additional info (you can download it at no charge).

Comment: Wish I could vote 1000 up's!!!

To your question, there are 1 and 0's for Recession. I didn't check on the sample I provided you to see if there were any 1's there. 

Thanks again!

Comment: My last question is, why isn't Open the dependent variable in the formula in the plot function? 
   
    plot(svm_linear, formula=Open~Freq, data=yelp_train)   ?